# How to add to the Column the PRODUCT of two other columns?

Tags: c#, sql, product

I am working on a project for a Market (Mini Market). And I want to create a Storage Table where I have all my products. And in this table there is a `QUANTITY Column` and the `PURCHASE PRICE` Column. And I want to add the TOTAL column. In the total column it should show me the price of:

```
TOTAL = QUANTITY * PURCHASE PRICE
```

And I wanted to ask you about how should I do this (`TOTAL = QUANTITY * PURCHASE PRICE`)? I there any option to do this while I am creating the Table in *SQL SERVER*? Or I have to do this in the *C#* code?

Please help me guys?

Comment: Why do you want to store this in the table?  Why not just calculate it when selecting from the database?

Comment: @Kaf - I don't understand. If the purchase price depends on date, then what are you storing in the purchase price column of the Storage table?

Comment: @SystemDown I see, I got it wrong I thought price was referencing... nuts

Answer (score 4):

In theory, you *shouldn't* do this at all - in relational databases, derived fields should not be stored in the database, but derived as required.

Comment: Or create a view with the expression as a calculated field.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Update MyTableName Set
    Total = Quantity * PurchasePrice
```

but you should consider just calculating this on the fly in select queries that need it, or adding a computed column.

```
Alter Table MyTableName  
Add Column Total = Quantity * PurchasePrice
```